# how to create view of field collection in drupal 7

Tags: view, drupal-7, drupal-field-collection

when i am creating a view of field collection they give error when we add fields in view
error is that:

An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 500
Debugging information follows.
Path: /en/admin/structure/views/view/new_page/preview/page/ajax
StatusText: error
ResponseText: Exception: Invalid field name given: field_translations is not a Field Collection field. in FieldCollectionItemEntity->__construct() (line 210 of /home)

how handle this problem

Answer (score 0):

To create field collection view you need to add relationship to the Field collection first and than you can use it. The above error seems like you're using a wrong field.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the field `field_translations` still exists as a field collection field on your installation (probably not anymore). Apparently removed fields remain inside the database table of Field Collection.

To **solve** this:

1. Take a database backup of your current installation (just to make sure)
2. go to your database, find the table `field_collection_item` and
   explore it
3. find all the items referencing to field mentionned in the error (in
   this case this would be `field_translations`)
4. Remove all these items and clear the cache of your Drupal
   installation

([Source](https://www.drupal.org/node/1938620#comment-7166930))